# Java - Needing not needed exception catching or throwing

Tags: java, exception, stream

So in Java for this example, why does the exception need to be thrown, when it never actually happens?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Files{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException //Why does exception need to be thrown
    {
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("myfile");
        os.close();
    }
```

Why does Java require this?

Answer (score 3):

It needs to throw it because `new FileOutputStream()` can throw this exception. See [Specifying the Exceptions Thrown by a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html). Alternatively instead of having the method throw the exception, you could also surround with `try...catch`:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("myfile");
    os.close();
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both lines below throw a checked exception and as per Java it must be either handled or must be declared so that callers can decide what should be done.

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("myfile");
os.close();
```

In this case the first line throws FileNotFoundException where as later throws IOException. As IOException is a parent of FileNotFoundException, we have option to declare just IOException.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the oracle docs for [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File)), you can see this :

> Throws: FileNotFoundException - if the file exists but is a directory
>   rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or
>   cannot be opened for any other reason SecurityException - if a
>   security manager exists and its checkWrite method denies write access
>   to the file.

This is for the call to the constructor `FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("myfile");`. So, this is why the compiler asks you to explicitly check for (handle) `IOException`.

The same applies to `close()` method.

Answer (score 1):

the constructor

```
FileOutputStream("myfile");
```

throws `FileNotFoundException` which extends `IOException`.
so you can throw `IOException` or `FileNotFoundException` and it is the same thing.
you can also throw `Exception` for the same reason